# Geolocation-marker with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, ng-map

I have a AngularJS application that displays a ngmap, however, i want to use [this](https://chadkillingsworth.github.io/geolocation-marker/) library to mark the current location of user.

I already have downloaded the library using bower. My question is, **how do I use it with ngmap?**

Sorry for bad English.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the current users location, you need to check if their browser supports geolocation...

```
if(navigator.geolocation){
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position){
        var latitude = position.coords.latitude;
        var longitude = position.coords.longitude;
```

if thats true then we make a map variable with the geolocation:

```
var geolocalpoint = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude);
        map.setCenter(geolocalpoint);

        var mapOptions = {
            zoom: 8,
            center: geolocalpoint,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        }
```

then we make the marker

```
//Place a marker
        var geolocation = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: geolocalpoint,
            map: map,
            title: 'Your geolocation',
            icon: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_green.png'
        });
    });
}
```

the part where it says

```
map.setCenter(geolocalpoint);
```

that centers the map around the persons geolocation, if you dont want that just remove it:) Hope i helped

Comment: Thanks for your help! I got the way in which you told me. But I really wanted to use the library I said. Is there a way to use it with ngmap?

Comment: Im sorry I am not familiar with ngmap